# What should I do to schedule block and release IP addresses rules in Windows Server?

Tags: windows, iis, powershell, ftp

I am running a windows server for file sharing. There are about 500 people want to receive data from me. I set an FTP site in IIS, but I can only allow 50 people to connect at the same time, due to the capacity limitation of my server and bandwidth (upgrade the server and bandwidth or move to cloud is not an option and those people are not mind to wait).

So I am thinking to do like this: every IP can only connect my FTP for 1 hour, then it will be disconnected and blocked for 1 hour, to release the seat for the others. After 1 hour, the same IP can log in again for another 1 hour.

Where and how can I set to make this happen? In task scheduler, or firewall and IIS setting, or 3rd party software, or maybe scripts in PowerShell?

Comment: Microsoft IIS does not have that feature. Find a third party FTP solution or build your own.

Answer (score 0):

In IIS you can limit the number of simultaneous login. Edit the Website detail and check the option; **Limit number of connections**.

[Sites | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/hh831681(v=ws.11)#Edit_Limits)

> Select this option to limit the number of connections allowed to a
>   website. In the corresponding box, enter the number of connections to
>   which you want to limit the website. The value must be an integer
>   between 0 and 4294967295 (unlimited). Setting the number to be
>   unlimited circumvents constant administration if your connections tend
>   to fluctuate. However, system performance can be negatively affected
>   if the number of connections exceeds your system resources.
>   Restricting a website to a specified number of connections can keep
>   performance stable.

On the other side you can let them connect all at once and use a router to allocate the maximum bandwidth you are ready to give them.

People are used to slow connection and will adapt, but are not used to get blocked after a period of time.

As such I suggest to limit the number of connection or allow them all, but not using script for banning the user in between as it can have a bad impact, like cutting a download in the middle and the user cant connect back.